# How to calculate size of tables which are saved on disk? (PosgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

How to calculate size of tables which are saved on disk?
Based on my internet searching, how to calculate the length of the table based on the formula:

8KB × ceil(number of records / floor(floor(8KB × fillfactor - 24) / (28 + data length of 1 record)))

Example:

```
Column    |     Type      |
aid      | integer       |
bid      | integer       |
abalance | integer       |
filler   | character(84) |
```

data length of 1 record = aid(4 bytes) + bid(4 bytes) + abalance(4 bytes) + filler(84 bytes + 1 byte) = 97 byte
The data length of a record must be rounded to 8 bytes.

=> Data length of 1 record is 104 bytes.

Therefore, I think that 1 character is contained in 1 byte of memory.
However,  column "filler" can be input with 84 characters "a" (single byte) or 84 characters "あ" (double-byte)

I don’t know why double-byte character can be contained in single byte character?
Can you explain to me this question?

Comment: The default for character encoding in Postgres is UTF-8. So `'a'` uses only one byte indeed, but `'あ'` would need to byte. You shouldn't use the `character` type to begin with (`varchar` or even `text` is a much better choice). The length restriction defines the number of **characters** not bytes. So the column could actually need up to 84 * 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler. Use `pg_relation_size` to calculate the size of one relation alone (without the associated TOAST tables and indexes) or `pg_total_relation_size` to include all associated objects.